# Technologies to use in react native authentication

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-navigation

I hope this is an ok question to ask here.
I want to build a social media app that the user can explore without being logged in and where the user can only do stuff like comment etc. when he is logged in.
Now mostly I find ressources about autentication where you first have to create an account and then can interact with the app. Can anyone maybe recommend me ressources on how to structure an app where the user does not necessarily has to log in? any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

So, the feature you're referring to must be implemented on the backend and has nothing to do with the frontend. You must construct a backend api in which some routes are secured, requiring a user to supply a token, while others are unprotected, i.e., public, allowing anybody to access it.
To easily carry out this I would suggest you to take a look for [strapi](https://strapi.io/) as it comes with everything out of the box, even the authentication part, follow some tutorial on youtube to get an idea.